# scrlettr2: How to remove side marks?

Tags: koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

I need to create a letter using the `scrlettr2` package. For this purpose, I wrote the LaTeX document given below.

But when I compile it I see marks on the side (see 3 red ellipses on the left).

[image: Screenshot]

How can I remove them?

Here's the source code:

```
% koma_env.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,backaddress=off]{scrlttr2}
% \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[english]{babel}
% \usepackage{url}



\setkomavar{fromname}{\{\{Landlord Name\}\}}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\{\{Landlord Name\}\} \\ \{\{Landlord Correspondence Address Line 1\} \\ \{\{Landlord Correspondence Line 2 (if applicable)\}\} \\ \{\{Town/City\}\} \\ \{\{County\}\} \\ \{\{Postcode\}\}}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{\{\{Tenant Names\}\} \\ \{\{Property Address Line 1\}\} \\ \{\{Property Address Line 2 (if applicable)\}\}
\\ \{\{Town/City\}\} \\ \{\{County\}\} \\ \{\{Postcode\}\}}

\KOMAoptions{fromphone=false,fromfax=false}
\setkomavar{subject}{Pre Check-Out Inspection at \{\{1st line of Property\}\}}

\opening{Dear \{\{Tenant Names\}\}}

Your tenancy is due to come to an end on \{\{date\}\}. I would like to arrange an inspection at the property before the tenancy ends to identify anything that may lead me to retain some of your deposit if not addressed by the time I retake possession.

Carrying out this inspection prior to the tenancy ending will give you the opportunity to tackle anything raised and ensure I can return the maximum amount of deposit to you when the tenancy ends

I would like to carry out the inspection on \{\{date\}\} at \{\{time\}\}. It would be best if you were present then if anything is identified we can discuss this and be clear on what would be required to rectify it. Please can you contact me as soon as possible to confirm whether or not this is convenient.

If you do not wish to be present I have a set of keys to access the property and will send you the results of the inspection. Please let me know either way at your earliest convenience.

\closing{Kind Regards}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,backaddress=off,foldmarks=false]{scrlttr2}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply adding the KOMA-option

```
\KOMAoptions{foldmarks=off}
```

to the preamble will remove them.