# Hide fold marks in dinbrief

Tags: dinbrief

Can I remove fold marks from dinbrief letter documents?

[image: culprit fold marks]

The solutions in [scrlettr2: How to remove side marks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164722/scrlettr2-how-to-remove-side-marks) don't help with dinbrief.

Looking at [Dinbrief manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/dinbrief/dinbrief.pdf) ([archive wayback link of originally linked document](https://web.archive.org/web/20200513173407/http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/dinbrief/dinbrief.pdf)), there seems to be no (documented) way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\nowindowtics` in the preamble.

The linked manual states on page 10:

> \nowindowtics
>         Es werden keine Faltmarkierungen am linken Briefrand ausgedruckt.

[image: manual page]

In English this means that using `\nowindowtics` will disable printing of the fold marks on the left side of the letter.

Please see the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{dinbrief}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\backaddress{Max Mustermann, Musterstr. 1, 12345 Musterstadt}
\signature{Max Mustermann}
\place{Musterstadt}
\nowindowrules

\nowindowtics % <=======================================================


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
    DIN e.V.\\
    Am DIN-Platz\\
    Burggrafenstraße 6\\
    10787 Berlin}


\subject{DIN 676 für Geschäftsbriefe}

\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}

die DIN Norm 676 sieht zwei Formate für Geschäftsbriefe vor: die erste
Falzmarke ist einmal 87\,mm von der Oberkante des Briefbogens entfernt und
einmal 105\,mm. Können Sie eines der beiden Formate besonders empfehlen?

\closing{Mit freundlichem Gruß}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting letter without fold marks]

There is no need to add commands like

```
\ka@db@foldmarklen=0truemm
\ka@db@perfmarklen=0truemm
```

to the letter preamble, which were suggested in [the other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491021/77844).

Comment: Nice. What does "mwe" mean? ("Please see the following mwe")

Comment: @qubodup  Please see this link: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 0):

Looking through `dinbrief.cls`, I found that adding

```
\ka@db@foldmarklen=0truemm
\ka@db@perfmarklen=0truemm
```

to the preamble removes them visually.

I do this in LyX in `Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble`.