# Use Dinbrief without addresses (LyX)

Tags: lyx, dinbrief

How to remove the From and To area in Dinbrief using LyX?

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to [Hide fold marks in dinbrief](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491020/hide-fold-marks-in-dinbrief/491021#491021), add

```
\def\ka@db@placetoaddress{}
\def\ka@db@placefromaddress{}
```

to the preamble.

In LyX, go to `Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble` and paste the lines there
[image: menu]
[image: settings]
[image: result]